# Adding text to explicit meta node labels from table

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I have some metadata in a table that I am including as bar labels in my plot. I would like to specify that these labels are timings, e.g., 15.8 secs. I don't know how to get the 'secs' text to be appended to the labels.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
  c1 c2  c3 c4 c5 c6 c7    c8  c9  c10  c11 
  1  94  0  5  6  6 15.8  2.0 37.5 42.3 42.3 
  2  93  0  5  7  7 16.1  2.1 30.7 43.1 42.5 
  3  97  0 11 13 13 18.6  1.9 39.0 51.6 51.9 
  4  87 34 93 93 93 34.6 34.6 93.8 93.3 92.4 
}\inittable
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar, bar width=10pt,
    width=6in, height=2.5in,
    ymin=-5, ymax=120, ytick={0,50,100},
    xmin=0, xmax=5, xtick={1,2,3,4},
    point meta=explicit,
    nodes near coords, every node near coord/.append style={
      anchor= west, rotate=90, font=\footnotesize},
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    ]
    \addplot table[x=c1,y=c2,meta=c7] {\inittable};
    \addplot table[x=c1,y=c3,meta=c8] {\inittable};
    \addplot table[x=c1,y=c4,meta=c9] {\inittable};
    \addplot table[x=c1,y=c5,meta=c10] {\inittable};
    \addplot table[x=c1,y=c6,meta=c11] {\inittable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of `node near coords` is `\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta`: it simply prints the point meta value as a number. But it does so within a Ti*k*Z node, therefore you can simply add text to it and it will go in the node too. So, what you want to do can be achieved with `nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}~secs}`. However, if you do this, you'll see that a few of the “secs” extend above the upper axis border, so you'll want to also add something like `enlarge y limits={upper, abs value=20}`. These two changes will give you the following output:

[image]

However, personally, I would rather use `siunitx` and the `s` symbol for the second, like this:

```latex
nodes near coords={%
  ${\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta} \, \si{\second}$%
}
```

Note the `xtick distance=1` and `ytick distance=50` that simplify your code a tiny bit. Also, I use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` to make sure the output will remain the same even in future versions of `pfgplots`.

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  c1 c2  c3 c4 c5 c6 c7    c8  c9  c10  c11
  1  94  0  5  6  6 15.8  2.0 37.5 42.3 42.3
  2  93  0  5  7  7 16.1  2.1 30.7 43.1 42.5
  3  97  0 11 13 13 18.6  1.9 39.0 51.6 51.9
  4  87 34 93 93 93 34.6 34.6 93.8 93.3 92.4
}\inittable

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar, bar width=10pt,
    width=6in, height=2.5in,
    ymin=-5, ymax=120, ytick distance=50,
    xmin=0, xmax=5, xtick distance=1,
    point meta=explicit,
    enlarge y limits={upper, abs value=5},
    nodes near coords={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta} \, \si{\second}$},
    every node near coord/.append style={
      anchor=west, rotate=90, font=\footnotesize,
    },
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    ]
    \addplot table[x=c1,y=c2,meta=c7] {\inittable};
    \addplot table[x=c1,y=c3,meta=c8] {\inittable};
    \addplot table[x=c1,y=c4,meta=c9] {\inittable};
    \addplot table[x=c1,y=c5,meta=c10] {\inittable};
    \addplot table[x=c1,y=c6,meta=c11] {\inittable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a very clear response. I have gratefully accepted your solution.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.